# How to match this with sed?

Tags: sorting, sed

I have a list of email addresses. I want to remove the ones that start with numbers and capital letters only. For example if the file contains:

```
0035EA7C@xxxx.com
A7C0035E@zzzz.com
email@yyy.com
```

I need to delete the first 2 lines in SSH.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` to get the desired result:

```
grep -v '^[0-9[:upper:]]\+@'
```

`^` matches the beginning of a line. `[...]` is a character class, it contains digits and uppercase letters. it must be present once or more `\+`. `@` stands for itself.

Answer (score 0):

Whit a [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution :

```
awk '/^[^[:upper:]0-9]+@/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^[A-Z0-9]/d' file
```